# How to debug Sitecore Helix Feature using Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: habitat

I'd like to debug a Sitecore Helix Feature using Visual Studio 2017.
Is it possible or just the Website Project?

Comment: you should publish dll related to project make sure pdb file should be publish if you are deploying manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Richard's Answer. Just keep few points in notice while debugging:

1. Attach you process to correct managed pool 
   [image]
2. Publish your dll's to your instance so that your breakpoints should load properly. Keep your profile in "Debug" mode and not in "Release"
3. Your feature and foundation must be published properly to your instance.
4. Your controller rendering has correct details of your controller and action method and dll.

Answer (score 2):

Its perfectly possible. You just need to attach Visual Studio to your `w3wp.exe` process.

1. In Visual Studio, select **Debug / Attach to Process** (or press CTRL+ALT+P).
2. In the **Attach to Process** dialog box, find the program that you want to attach to from the **Available Processes** list. For this it will be one of the `w3wp.exe` processes:

[image]

You will need to select the `Show processes from all users` check box.

3. In the **Attach to** box, click **Select**.

In the Select Code Type dialog box, click Debug these code types and select the types to debug.

Click OK.

Click Attach.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx

Comment: Hi Richard, I did and I have a break-point inside my Feature Project ->Controller but It never stops there. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Make sure you are deploying the `Debug` configuration and not the `Release`

Comment: Also small trick - Click on "Process" column in screenshot above which will change order of processes (making it descending) and w3wp will be up ;) So you don't need to scroll all the way down...

Comment: Or you can use Visual Studio extension that adds shortcuts to Tools menu: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thebread.AttachToAllTheThings. Then can take it a step further and assign a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You can use the Modules debug window to check whether your assembly has symbols loaded. If not, this could indicate a Release build or problem with your pdbs.